# Retrieve data from the list on the basis of value in Python

Tags: python

In a Python program, I'm storing student information in a list, which I want to retrieve on the basis of value (class name).

Let's say I want to print complete student details. I'll write this code:

```
for i in range(len(studentDetails)):
    for j in range(len(studentDetails[i])):
        print(studentDetails[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

**Data**

```
studentDetail = [studentName, "Class: ", studentClass, "Marks:", studentMarks, "Grade: ", studentGrade]

[Dostoevsky, "Class: ", 1, "Marks: ", 100, "Grade: ", "A+"]
[Tolstoy, "Class: ", 1, "Marks: ", 90, "Grade: ", "A-"]
[Chekhov, "Class: ", 2, "Marks: ", 80, "Grade: ", "A"]
[Kafka, "Class: ", 2, "Marks: ", 75, "Grade: ", "B"]
```

I now want to print this way from the following data:

**Result**

```
Summary
Class 1
Dostoevsky    100    A+
Tolstoy        90    A-
Class 2
Chekhov       80     A
Kafka         75     B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
studentDetails = [["Dostoevsky", "Class: ", 1, "Marks: ", 100, "Grade: ", "A+"],
                  ["Tolstoy",    "Class: ", 1, "Marks: ", 90,  "Grade: ", "A-"],
                  ["Chekov",     "Class: ", 2, "Marks: ", 80,  "Grade: ", "A" ],
                  ["Kafka",      "Class: ", 2, "Marks: ", 75,  "Grade: ", "B"]]

studentDetails.sort()                        # Sort the list by alphabetical order first
studentDetails.sort(key = lambda x: x[2])    # Sort the list by second element(classes)

print("Summary")

curClass = 0                                 # Current class nummber
for i in studentDetails:                     # Loops through all the student details
    if curClass != i[2]:                     # If the currect class number is not equal to the class number that's already printed
        curClass = i[2]                      # Replace the currect class number
    print("Class", curClass)                 # Print out the current class number
print(i[0], i[4], i[6])                      # Print out info
```

This works even when you add more data or class numbers. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks :). Just a small change, `print(i[0], i[4], i[6])` should be under `for` loop. please edit your answer. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "IF statements" to solve your problem

```
for i in range(len(studentDetail)):
   if studentDetail[i][2]== 1: #it will check in which Class student is 
      print(studentDetail[i][0],studentDetail[i][4],studentDetail[i][6])

   if studentDetail[i][2]== 2: #it will check in which Class student is 
      print(studentDetail[i][0],studentDetail[i][4],studentDetail[i][6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
numOfClasses = 2
for c in range(numOfClasses):
    print("Class:",c+1)
    for i in range(len(studentDetail)):
       if studentDetail[i][2] == c+1: 
          print(studentDetail[i][0],studentDetail[i][4],studentDetail[i][6])
```